# iterator hasnext() returns true but next() throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, iterator

When I debugged my code I found that the `hasNext()` method of `Iterator` returned `true`, but the `next()` method threw NoSuchElementException.

Below is my code:

```
 Collection<TradeStock> restBuy=em.createQuery("select t from TradeStock ...t.getResultList();

if(!restBuy.isEmpty())
{
    Iterator itrest=restBuy.iterator();
    while(itrest.hasNext())
    {
        TradeStock ts=(TradeStock)itrest.next();
        x+=ts.getTradeExecutedQuantity();
    }
}
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `isEmpty` check there; if it's empty the `while` loop just wouldn't be entered

Comment: and if you make it `Iterator<TradeStock>`, you won't need to do the casting.

Comment: regarding the exception, are any other threads trying to modify this iterator

Comment: @Raze2dust if you try to change a collection when the iterator iterates it - the iterator will throw IllegalArgumentException - this is the "fail-fast" property of the Iterator class.

Comment: while loop is entered and the exception is thrown at the next() call. and there is no other thread trying to modify it, what do i do?

Comment: @alfasin It's the `ConcurrentModificationException`. Whether it is thrown or not depends on the implementation. I am not sure what implementation of `Collection` is returned by `em.createQuery()` here

Comment: @z22 hmm.. what does restBuy.size() say?

Comment: @alfasin and Raze2dust- everything works fine till the next() call is made, collection is returned, while loop returns true and gets executed- only the next() call fails and throws exception

Comment: @z22 Is the `em` object a standard library? Which one is it? I just want to confirm it implements the `.iterator` method correctly.

Comment: @Raze2dust size() returns 1(meaning it fetches 1 record), em is an object of entityManager class

Comment: if you see in the code, i have used .getResultList(), it returns collection.

Comment: Indeed, it returns a collection: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html#getResultList()

Comment: What's the complete stack trace?

Comment: thank you all for your support! the code worked when i restarted the server and redeployed my app, so nothing was wrong with the code i guess, i cant understand this strange behavior of glassfish sorry to trouble you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code worked when i restarted the server and redeployed my app, so nothing was wrong with the code i guess, i cant understand this strange behavior of glassfish!

Comment: If I was to hazard a guess, it would be that you'd previously made a change and forgotten to redeploy.  (Or maybe the redeploy quietly failed.)  So the source code that you were looking at while debugging wasn't the same as the code that was actually running.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "debugged my code" do you mean debug using a debugger, like in Eclipse?
If your evaluated expression (*Expressions* tab in Eclipse) includes *itrest.next()* then the debugger invokes the *next()* method and modifies the state of your Iterator, without your code being aware of it. 
Try debugging this either without evaluating *itrest.next()* or with log messages

Comment: I can't believe it, this is exactly what has happening in my case. I deleted all the watched expressions and all is OK now. +1 from me