# LinkedList Iterator next() throwing NoSuchElementException even when called after hasNext() returning true

Tags: java, linked-list, nosuchelementexception

LinkedList Iterator next() throwing NoSuchElementException even when called after hasNext() returning true.

Environment: Java 6 on Sun Solaris

Any idea why I'm hitting this exception on next() method call?

```
// lines is an instance of LinkedList
// writer is a FileWriter, Believe that is irrelevant to issue
while(lines.hasNext()){
    int i = 0;
    do {
            writer.write(lines.next());
            writer.newLine();
            i++;
    } while (lines.hasNext() && i < targetLineCount);
    // Some more code... 
}
```

**Update with More Code**

```
public class MyClass { // Only one instance of this class is used across application
    private List<String> master = new LinkedList<String>();
    // Other instance members to tune this instance behaviour

    public MyClass(){
        // Read Source & populate master
    }

    public boolean writeDataSlot(Writer writer, int targetLineCount){ // Can be called by different Threads
        Ierator<String> lines = master.iterator();
        while(lines.hasNext()){
            int i = 0;
            do {
                writer.write(lines.next());
                writer.newLine();
                i++;
            } while (lines.hasNext() && i < targetLineCount);
            // Some more code to populate slot from different source.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing anything with the iterator or the list in `// Some more code...` fragment?

Comment: No.. Iterator is not used in `// Some more code` area

Comment: And what about the list, for with the iterator is from?

Comment: List is not modified, as that instance is visible only current thread. Also, if that happened, I should have got `ConcurrentModificationException`, not `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Well that's weird, since your code as it stands works for me... except that `lines` should be an instance of `Iterator<Xyz>` and you have another variable which is an instance of `LinkedList<Xyz>` (probably, Xyz = String). Can you post more code?

Comment: Yes. I have a `List<String>` which holds reference to `LinkedList<String>` populated with around a million string objects and never modified after initial loading of Application. `Iterator<String>` is created in per Thread basics and they write to different `Writer`s. The weird thing is - This code is working for few hundreds strings in Windows, Linux & Solaris. In Production, this is executed with Strings instance in millions scale & Solaris. Will that make any difference?

Comment: When you say `per Thread` - it's multi-threaded? can you post more code, and described the multi-threaded architecture.

Comment: @vikingsteve Updated Question with more code.

Comment: @RKajaMohideen `ConcurrentModificationException` is not guaranteed to be thrown when the list is modified in another thread. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html "Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis." In other words, try using a synchronized list (wrap master in a call to `Collections.synchronizedList`) and see what happens.

Comment: But @JAB, my List instance is not exposed and I know the class doesn't update it once it is populated in the class constructor :-(

Comment: @RKajaMohideen Your list instance is not exposed, but it can still be accessed by multiple threads using the methods of your singleton instance. I suggest trying the synchronized list, and more importantly synchronizing ON the list such that no other threads can access it while the iterator is in use. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

Comment: (Of course, if you can guarantee that nothing will write to/be able to write to the list then synchronization would just cause a performance penalty, but as far as I can tell something somewhere _is_ modifying the list, so...)

Comment: @Thomas Wouldn't each instance have its own `master`, though? In the example, `master` is filled out in the constructor, meaning even if it's not a singleton all instances should have the same data in their `master`s. (Well, unless the source gets depleted or is changed somehow after the first construction.)

Comment: Oh, interesting, someone else had a similar issue and apparently a server restart+redeployment fixed the issue for them. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10975058/138772) If you're doing similar server work, perhaps try that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @JAB. I'm using JBoss. I have just triggered a build with `synchronization` block. Will also try re-deploy if the issue still persists.

Comment: @RKajaMohideen Try redeploying without the synchronization block as well, as if the issue was just the deployment and the master list is truly never modified after creation then synchronization will just needlessly slow things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a threading issue, as Axel pointed out.

What happens if you make this method `synchronized` ?

```
public synchronized boolean writeDataSlot(Writer writer, int targetLineCount)
```

Comment: Using a synchronized list and synchronizing on the list might be better if the iteration is just one part of the method and the rest doesn't require mutual exclusion.

Comment: @JAB yes, good suggestion, though starting with `synchronized` on the method will naturally isolate the issue quickly.

Comment: Don't know what is the real problem. But the issue is not occurring anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I see these possibilities:

1. `lines` is used from another thread
2. `lines.next()` is called in `// some more code...`
3. `lines` is bound to another instance in `// some more code...`